# How many morphism $\mathbb{F}_q\to \mathbb{F}_{q^n}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory, finite-fields

Sorry for my bad English.

Let $q$ be prime $p$ power, and $n>0$ be integer, and $\mathbb{F}_q$, $\mathbb{F}_{q^n}$ be finite fields.

Now how many morphisms of field $\mathbb{F}_q\to \mathbb{F}_{q^n}$?

Since ${\rm Aut}(\mathbb{F}_q)={\rm Gal}(\mathbb{F}_q /\mathbb{F}_p)\cong \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$,
I think $\#{\rm Mor}(\mathbb{F}_q, \mathbb{F}_{q^n})\ge n.$

Comment: Since $x^q=x$ for every $x\in\Bbb F_q$, the range of any such field morphism is the unique subfield $\{x:x^q=x\}\subseteq\Bbb F_{q^n}$, so we're basically counting the automorphisms.

Comment: I think for example $f: \mathbb{F}_q\to \mathbb{F}_{q^n}$ such that $f(x):=x^{q^2}$ is morphism of field which isn't immersion. So I think $ \# Mor (\mathbb{F}_q,\mathbb{F}_{q^n})$ make sense. What is wrong?